# HTML : Make text above another text bootstrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm creating two text with p tag and I want one to be above the other one,I don't know if should I use z-index or not but the big text "Spectacles en vedette" should appear like a background image on the section,  how can I correct my code :

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-s row justify-content-center ">
      <p class="bg-title">Spectacles en vedette</p>
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
        <p class="section-title">Les Meilleurs Spectacles</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark see-all-btn">Voir tout</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**

```
@import '../../styles/global/_variables.sass'
.section-title
  font-family: Raleway
  font-size: 40px
  font-weight: bold
  font-style: normal
  font-stretch: normal
  line-height: 1.2
  letter-spacing: normal
  text-align: center
  color: #303338
  padding-top: 92px

.header-s
  height: 205px

.see-all-btn
  float: right
  margin-top: 99px
  font-family: Raleway
  font-size: 16px
  font-weight: 600
  line-height: 1.19
  text-align: center
  color: $secondary-black

.bg-title
  font-family: Pacifico
  font-size: 117px
  font-weight: normal
  font-style: normal
  font-stretch: normal
  line-height: 1.2
  letter-spacing: normal
  text-align: center
  color: #f5f5f6
```

Comment: You are on the right path.  Just remember that the other font you include (in this case Pacifico) should be included as a web font.

Comment: yeah just I have to add aboslute position de bg-title